# add extra option field on woocommerce quick shop archive page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I recently added a plugin to my wordpress woocommerce named "[Extra product options For WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woo-extra-product-options/)".
I added a url getter field to single product pages as shown as below:
[url field on single product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH1G4.jpg)

but I need that it shows on the quick shop archive page too as well. look at the image below:
[I need url getter field goes on the red section I draw on image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jA4Ah.jpg)

how can I do that ? is there any hook to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind..I found the answer:
just add the code below to your function.php:

```
add_filter('thwepof_hook_name_before_single_product','thwepof_change_prepare_hook');
    function thwepof_change_prepare_hook(){
    return 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button';
}
```